# Positive elements in * Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If one has a * Algebra $W$ one can define the notion of a positive element via the spectrum $\sigma$:

$A \in W$ is positive if $A^* = A$ and $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{R}_{≥0}$.

If $W$ can be given a norm so that it becomes a  C* Algebra then this is equivalent to the notion that there exists a $B \in W$ so that $A=B^* B$.

The proof of existence of such a $B$ that I have seen require completeness of $W$, and it doesn't seem unlikely that you can construct * Algebras where you have positive elements that are not decomposable in this way.

But is it true in a general * Algebra that if $A=B^*B$ that then $A$ is a positive element?

Comment: Interesting! Clearly $B^*B$ is self-adjoint, and the result is not so hard to prove if $B$ is itself self-adjoint (use spectral mapping for polynomials, e.g. [Murphy theorem 1.2.1](https://books.google.nl/books?id=omviBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&hl=nl&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false)). However, I have no clue for the general case. I don't know (and cannot find) a lot about general $*$-algebras. For instance, do we know whether the sum of positive elements is again positive? Or can we perhaps restrict to some *-subalgebra without losing large parts of the spectrum?

Comment: Oh, what I claimed is also incorrect. I made the mistake of assuming that a self-adjoint element $B$ satisfies $\sigma(B) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. While this is true in $C^*$-algebras, it is not true in arbitrary $*$-algebras. Thus, it may happen that $B^*B$ is not positive even if $B$ is self-adjoint. I will post an answer to your question shortly, which also addresses this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no: $B^*B$ need not be positive, even if the algebra is unital and commutative and $B$ is self-adjoint. Consider the $\mathbb C$-algebra $\mathbb C[X]$ of polynomials in one indeterminate with coefficients in $\mathbb C$. We equip $\mathbb C[X]$ with involution $p \mapsto \overline{p}$, that is, complex conjugation of the coefficients. This turns $\mathbb C[X]$ into a unital $*$-algebra over the complex numbers. Note that the only invertible elements in $\mathbb C[X]$ are the non-zero constant polynomials. Now the degree one polynomial $f := X$ is self-adjoint, so we have $f^*f = X^2$. Note however that $X^2 - \lambda$ is not invertible for any choice of $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, so we have $\sigma(X^2) = \mathbb C$.

This example shows that spectral theory fails dramatically in the absence of a complete norm. Recall that the spectrum of an element in a Banach algebra is compact, so the above example shows that there is no Banach algebra norm on $\mathbb C[X]$.

There seems to be only one thing we can say with certainty: an element of the form $B^*B$ is always self-adjoint, since we have $(B^*B)^* = B^*B^{**} = B^*B$.

Comment: This is a very nice example, if you introduce a norm (e.g. sup-norm on the unit ball or just the $L^2$ norm on it) and take the completion suddenly a lot more things are invertible.

Comment: Exactly! Be careful, though: if you embed the polynomial ring in a space of functions in one *complex* variable, then the involution I give does not correspond with the pointwise conjugation. For instance, the conjugate of $X : z \mapsto z$ on the complex closed unit disk $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ is the complex conjugation $z \mapsto \overline{z}$, whereas $X$ is self-adjoint in $\mathbb C[X]$. Of course this problem disappears if we embed $\mathbb C[X]$ into a function space of one real variable.