# Positivity of element in an algebraic corner of a $*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $*$-algebras, with $A=pBp$ for some projection $p\in B$. Suppose we have an element $x\in A$ such that $x=b^* b$ for some $b\in B$.

*Question:* Is it true that $x=a^*a$ for some $a\in A$?

*Thoughts:* I suspect that this is false in general, although it seems to be true if $A$ and $B$ are $C^*$-algebras, by spectral permanence. But an explicit example of $*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ for which this is false (or a proof that it is true in general) would be appreciated.

**Added later:** If it helps, we may assume that $A$ and $B$ can be given norms so that they become $C^*$-algebras after completion with respect to these norms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. As a reminder the spectrum $\sigma_A(x)$ of an element of $A$ is defined to be:

$$\sigma_A(x)=\{\lambda \in\Bbb C\,\mid x-\lambda\Bbb 1\text{ is not invertible in }\widetilde A\}$$
here $\widetilde A$ is a unitisation of $A$ if $A$ is not unital, othewise it is $A$. Now if $A\subseteq B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra you have $\sigma_A(x)\cup \{0\} = \sigma_B(x)\cup\{0\}$ for any $x\in A$, that is the spectrum changes at most by adding a zero.

An element $x$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is positive if and only if any of the following equivalent conditions hold:

> 1. $x$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma_A(x)\subseteq \Bbb R_{≥0}$.
> 2. There is an $a\in A$ with $a^*a= x$.
> 3. There is a self-adjoint $a\in A$ with $a^2=x$.
> 4. For any state $\omega$ you have $\omega(x)≥0$.

In particular if $x=b^*b$ for a $b\in B$ you have that $x$ is positive in $B$, hence $x$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma_A(x)\cup\{0\}=\sigma_B(x)\cup\{0\}\subseteq \Bbb R_{≥0}$, whence $x$ is positive in $A$ and you find an $a\in A$ for which $a^*a=x$. So the notion of positivity is independent of including your algebra in a bigger one.

The above equivalences can be found in any book in $C^*$-algebras, like Murphy or Bratteli-Robinson.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent these equivalent conditions apply to general $*$-algebras. For example, from your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520974/positive-elements-in-algebras it seems that $x=b^*b$ does not imply that $x$ is positive in the sense of $*$-algebras.

Comment: Oh jeeze, looks like I didn't read your question carefully enough. Due to the tag c-star-algebras I thought you were talking about C*-algebras. I'd guess this is false in this context. I'll see if I can come up with a counter example.

Comment: @ougoah without a norm to help you you are in trouble. Consider the algebra generated by two elements, $a$, $p$ with $p^2=p$ and otherwise no relations. (This is $\Bbb C[G]$ where $G$ is the monoid generated by $a,p$ with those relations.) Choose $*$-operation defined by $p^*=p$, $a^*=a$. Then $x=pa^2p\in A$ and $pa^2p = (ap)^*(ap)$. But you cannot write $x$ as a square in $A$, as any square in $A$ must have a $p$ "in the middle".

Comment: Thanks. I've not thought much about $\mathbb{C}[G]$ where $G$ is a monoid before, so I may be missing the point here. But I wonder: if $A$ and $B$ can be given norms so that their completions are $C^*$-algebras, would the answer to the question be different?

Comment: It almost seems like you can embed the thing $\Bbb C[G]$ into a sub-algebra of $B(H)$ for $H$ an infinite dimensional Hilbert space (likely you must modify $*$). So my guess is that it is possible, but I'm not sure at all about this.